# Adding unique identifiers to duplicate values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create unique identifiers for values that are duplicates. Values that are duplicates are only 0's. The idea is to convert each zero to zero plus its position (0+1 for first row, 0+2 for second row etc). However the problem is the column also has other non duplicate values.

I have written this line of code to try and convert the zero values as stated but I am getting this error message

> TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching
>   types dtype('

Here is my code

```
seller_customer['customer_id'] = np.where(seller_customer['customer_id']==0, seller_customer['customer_id'] + seller_customer.groupby(['customer_id']).cumcount().replace('0',''))
```

Here is a sample of my data

```
{0: '7e468d618e16c6e1373fb2c4a522c969',
 1: '1c14a115bead8a332738c5d7675cca8c',
 2: '434dee65d973593dbb8461ba38202798',
 3: '4bbeac9d9a22f0628ba712b90862df28',
 4: '578d5098cbbe40771e1229fea98ccafd',
 5:  0,
 6:  0,
 7:  0}
```

Comment: Interesting. May be you need to write python function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    from pandas.util import hash_pandas_object
    import numpy as np
    df.x = np.where(df.x == 0, hash_pandas_object(df.x), df.x)
    df
```

Output:

```
                                      x
    0  7e468d618e16c6e1373fb2c4a522c969
    1  1c14a115bead8a332738c5d7675cca8c
    2  434dee65d973593dbb8461ba38202798
    3  4bbeac9d9a22f0628ba712b90862df28
    4  578d5098cbbe40771e1229fea98ccafd
    5                593769213749726025
    6              14559158595676751865
    7               4575103004772269825
```

They won't be sequential like the index but they will be unique (almost certainly, unless you encounter a hash collision)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you can just assign range values to those `id`s that are `0`:

```
df.loc[df['id']==0, 'id'] = np.arange((df['id']==0).sum()) + 1

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                 id
0  7e468d618e16c6e1373fb2c4a522c969
1  1c14a115bead8a332738c5d7675cca8c
2  434dee65d973593dbb8461ba38202798
3  4bbeac9d9a22f0628ba712b90862df28
4  578d5098cbbe40771e1229fea98ccafd
5                                 1
6                                 2
7                                 3
```

Or a shorter but slightly slower:

```
df.loc[df['id']==0, 'id'] = (df['id']==0).cumsum()
```